# Add cooldown when bot is reading every message in server (not commands)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm writing a bot that checks every message every user sends in my server and adds XP to a file. I've written the function to do this, but I want to add anti-spam where the bot only takes note of the message every 10 seconds (essentially a ten-second cooldown). Can someone please help with this? (edit: The cooldown must be per user)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if checkUser(message.author.id) == True:
        add = gcSPM(message.author.id)
        balancePlus(message.author.id, int(add))
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.guild)
...
```

Note I'm using the `commands` library. Don't use `on_message` to handle commands. There's an entire library for it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html

Also see: https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/

Comment: This isn't intended to respond to a command, it responds to any message sent in the server, like it says in the title. If it's possible to allow `bot.command()`  to respond to all messages I would be interested.

Comment: Then every message event needs to check when the last XP save happened. I would use `datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)` to make a timestamp for 10 minutes in the future, then check that on every message. If the current time is greater, the cooldown is over and you can save XP again.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but this adds the cooldown to EVERYONE rather than just that specific user, which is not what is needed.

Comment: Well you didn't ask per-user! :D I imagine a more complex lookup table of timestamps would work though. A dictionary mapping user ID's to last message makes sense to me. Then you can use the `message.author.id` when doing the lookup of the user.